# Monitoring CPU usage in GHz using Prometheus node_exporter

Tags: grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I use Prometheus node_exporter and grafana to monitor my server. I simply monitor CPU usage in percentage format, but I don't know how to monitor CPU in gigahertz format.
any ideas?

Comment: `CPU in gigahertz format` - that's not a CPU usage, but CPU frequency

Comment: yeah, you right
do you know how to monitor CPU frequency in GHz?is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
(max (node_cpu_frequency_max_hertz) by (instance)) / 2^30
```

2^30 give you em Ghz.